# Deleting from list in vue.js

Tags: html, json, vue.js

I am having some problem with my code. Iam trying to delete a "joke" from a list but it always takes out the joke that i typed in before the joke i am deleting. I don't quite get what i am doing wrong here.

```
delJoke(index) {
            this.setList.splice(index,1);
            this.viewJoke = {};
            console.log(this.setList.splice);
        }, 


<div class="col list-group-item" v-for="(view, index) in viewJoke" :key="index">
                            <div class="col">Joke: {{view.joke}} </div>
                            <div class="col"> Punchline: {{view.punchline}}</div>
                            <div class="col">Category: {{view.category}}</div>

                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" active href="#" v-for="joke in viewJoke"
                            @click="delJoke(index)"></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to pass joke object into function, and find index

```
delJoke(joke) {
  var index = this.setList.indexOf(joke)
  ... your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The index part has been a big headache.

Answer (score 0):

your delete button must be inside the `v-for`.

and the delete function should look like this

```
delJoke(index) {
    this.viewJoke = this.viewJoke.splice(index,1);
}
```